# Listing ".xlsx" files only from a selected folder

Tags: excel, vba

The aim is first to count the .xlsx files in a folder and state the number in a defined cell, then in a table below on the same sheet, list files from selected folders.

When listing .xlsx files from a selected folder it lists all the files regardless of the type.

Is there a way to list .xlsx files only?

```vb
Sub Outstanding39()

    'Count files from selected folder
    Dim folder_path As String
    Dim strtype As String
    Dim totalfiles As Variant

    strtype = "*.xlsx*"

    folder_path = Worksheets("Data2").Cells(83, 2).Value

    If Right(folder_path, 1) <> "\" Then folder_path = folder_path & "\"
    totalfiles = Dir(folder_path & strtype)

    Dim i As Integer

    While (totalfiles <> "")
        i = i + 1
        totalfiles = Dir
    Wend

    Worksheets("Open").Cells(15, 7).Value = i
    Worksheets("Open").Cells(15, 7).Select

    'List Files from selected folder
    Dim objFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim nextRow As Long

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Worksheets("Data2").Cells(83, 2).Value)

    nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        Cells(nextRow, 2) = objFile.Name
        Cells(nextRow, 16) = objFile.ParentFolder
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Why loop through the files twice?  You can list the files while you're counting them with `Dir()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the line "for each" add a condition to the file extension:

```
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If Right(objFile.Name, 4) = "xlsx" then
        Cells(nextRow, 2) = objFile.Name
        Cells(nextRow, 16) = objFile.ParentFolder
        nextRow = nextRow + 1
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

### List Files in Folder Using the FileSystemObject Object

- Another way is to use the Dir function.

```vb
Sub ListFolders()
    ' VBE->Tools->References->Microsoft Scripting Runtime
   
    ' Reference the workbook.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Build the folder path.
    Dim wsData As Worksheet: Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Data2")
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = CStr(wsData.Range("B83").Value)
    If Right(FolderPath, 1) <> pSep Then FolderPath = FolderPath & pSep
    
    ' Reference the FileSystemObject object.
    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    
    ' Check if the folder doesn't exist.
    If Not fso.FolderExists(FolderPath) Then
        MsgBox "The path '" & FolderPath & "' doesn't exist.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Reference the folder.
    Dim fsoFolder As Scripting.Folder: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    
    ' Calculate the first available row in the destination worksheet.
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet: Set wsDest = wb.Sheets("Open")
    Dim NextRow As Long
    NextRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    
    ' Loop, check, write and count.
    
    Dim fsoFile As Scripting.File
    Dim FileExtension As String
    Dim FilesCount As Long
    
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
    ' If you don't want to use the 'fsoFolder' variable, you can safely use:
    'For Each fsoFile In fso.GetFolder(FolderPath).Files
        FileExtension = fso.GetExtensionName(fsoFile.Path)
        If StrComp(FileExtension, "xlsx", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' is a match
            wsDest.Cells(NextRow, "B").Value = fsoFile.Name
            wsDest.Cells(NextRow, "P").Value = fsoFile.ParentFolder
            FilesCount = FilesCount + 1
            NextRow = NextRow + 1
        'Else ' is not a match; do nothing
        End If
    Next fsoFile
    
    ' Only now write the (counted) number of files to the cell.
    wsDest.Range("G15").Value = FilesCount
    
    MsgBox "Files listed: " & FilesCount, vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, the below IF statement worked well